# Python--Initializing variables using a variable in the current parameter

Tags: python

I too often find myself assigning a variable to `None` in the variable assignment, and I was wondering if there is a more efficient and less ugly way.

```
def Stringlength(String = "Hello", sLength = None):
    if sLength == None:
        sLength = len(String)
```

Here is an example. I want to assign `sLength` to the length of `String`. How can I do this in a more efficient way?

I am doing this because I am using it for my permutation code, which I recall using the same method, so please don't comment saying to write the variable later on :D

Comment: I could comment on your whitespace and naming, but the actual question is best answered, "you have the best way".  That is the common way, the readable way, (and it should be `is None`, not `== None`.)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible improvement to what you have is to replace `sLength == None` with `sLength is None`.  The latter is more accurate, and perhaps slightly more efficient.

Comment: Zen of Python: `explicit is better than implicit` :-)